Concept confusions on simple extension and conjugates
I find an example of constructing the simple extension by choosing $p(x)=x^3-2$, so it gives
$E_0=\frac{Q[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$ as a field. As we know, there are 3 roots for $p(x)=0$ in $\mathbb{C}$, which are $r_1=2^{1/3}, r_2=2^{1/3}e^{2\pi i/3},r_3=2^{1/3}e^{-2\pi i/3}$ and we define $E_1=Q(r_1), E_2=Q(r_2), E_3=Q(r_3)$. My confusion is,
(1) All of them are isomorphic, right? $E_0\simeq E_1\simeq E_2\simeq E_3$, but this seems strange because $E_1\subset \mathbb{R}$, but $E_2\not\subset \mathbb{R}$
(2) In complex analysis, we call $r_2$ and $r_3$ as conjugate roots, and they  are $\notin\mathbb{R}$, but $r_1\in \mathbb{R}$, so we treat $r_1, r_2, r_3$ differently in complex analysis. But here, in algebra, we call all three roots $r_1, r_2, r_3$ as conjugates, because they are the roots of the same irreducible polynomial $p(x)$. So we evenly treat them in algebra, right? Hence, the word "conjugate" has different meanings in complex analysis and in algebra, right?
(3) When we wrote $E_0$, it might refer to any one of $E_1, E_2, E_3$, right?
Thank you in advance!


Yes, they're all isomorphic. This is no stranger than a group having distinct subgroups which are isomorphic but not equal or not even conjugate. However, here's a much stranger fact: general field theory implies (in the presence of the axiom of choice) that these isomorphisms $E_1 \cong E_2 \cong E_3$ extend to automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$! So there are automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ that don't fix $\mathbb{R}$.

This is only because the base field is different in the two usages, namely $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$; they are actually special cases of the same general concept. Namely, given a field extension $K/F$ we say that two elements $\alpha, \beta \in K$ which are algebraic over $F$ are conjugate over $F$ (note that we're making the dependence on $F$ explicit here) iff they have the same minimal polynomials over $F$. Two complex numbers $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ are complex conjugates $a + bi, a - bi$ iff they are conjugate over $\mathbb{R}$ in this sense. However, in this setting we are studying conjugacy over $\mathbb{Q}$. So $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega \sqrt[3]{2}$ are conjugate over $\mathbb{Q}$ but not $\mathbb{R}$.

Technically it refers to none of them. $E_0$ as written is just an abstract field without a choice of embedding into $\mathbb{C}$, and there are three choices, namely the embeddings into $E_1, E_2, E_3$ respectively.



For your answer (1), in the last sentence, "$E_1, E_2, E_3$ extend to automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$", do you mean the splitting field $K=Q(r_1, r_2, r_3)$? hence the automorphism is on $K$, which fixes the base field $Q$. And this automorphism maps conjugate to conjugate, i,e, map $r_1$ to $r_2$, hence it does NOT fix $R$, right? For (2), if we set the base field as $\mathbb{R}$, and $E=\mathbb{R}(r_2, r_3)$, then the minimal polynomial is $p=x^2+r_1x+r_1^2$, right? We can also choose a smaller base field $Q(r_1)$ and $K=Q(r_1, r_2, r_3)$, the minimal poly is the same $p=x^2+r_1x+r_1^2$, right?

@GGplay: 1) the statement is also true of the splitting field, but no, I meant $\mathbb{C}$. That's why I said it is a much stranger fact! Automorphisms of the splitting field $K$ don't act on $\mathbb{R}$ but only on the much smaller intersection $K \cap \mathbb{R}$, whereas automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ act on all of $\mathbb{R}$. If this is confusing then don't worry about it, it's mostly just a funny piece of trivia but the point is that $\mathbb{R}$ can be moved around.

@GGplay: 2) I'm not sure I understand what you wrote, but to be clear, the minimal polynomial of $r_1$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $x - r_1$, which is linear, because $r_1$ is real. The minimal polynomial of both $r_2$ and $r_3$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $(x - r_2)(x - r_3)$, which is quadratic, and they are complex conjugates. Over $\mathbb{Q}$ the situation is that all three have the same minimal polynomial $x^3 - 2$, which is cubic, so they are all conjugates over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Sorry, let me re-state for (2), I want to use the same minimal poly $p=(x-r_2)(x-r_3)=x^2+r_1x+r_1^2$ in two scenarios, $p$ is irreducible on $R$ and irreducible on $Q$. Scenario #1, if we choose the base field as $R$, and splitting field $R(r_2, r_3)$, this is like the conjugate root case in complex analysis, but with a smaller extension field than $\mathbb{C}$. Scenario #2, if choose base field as $Q(r_1)$, and splitting field $K=Q(r_1, r_2, r_3)$, in this case, we construct a smaller base & extension field than scenario #1. Finally, both Scenario #1 and #2 have the same minimal poly $p$.

@GGplay: I'm not sure what $R$ means here; does this mean $\mathbb{R}$? If so the extension field is not smaller than $\mathbb{C}$. But yes, it's true that the minimal polynomial of $r_2, r_3 \in K$ over $E_1 = \mathbb{Q}(r_1)$ is $p$.

Yes, $R=\mathbb{R}$, sorry about that. Ah, right, $\mathbb{R}(r_2, r_3)=\mathbb{C}$, so it is not a smaller field than $\mathbb{C}$, it is exactly $\mathbb{C}$.

Yes, that's right.

Perhaps one possible way to justify "conjugates" is to use Galois groups. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the same minimal polynomial, then they are "Galois conjugates", i.e there is an element in the Galois group which takes one to the other. For example in your example complex conjugation is an element in the Galois group taking one complex root to the other. But there are other elements in the Galois group. The Galois group of the polynomial $x^3 -2$ has order $6$. In order to understand this group, you need to look at the field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$. The Galois group is the group of all automorphisms of $K$ that fix $\mathbb{Q},$ denoted by $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$. Since any element $\sigma \in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ acts as identity on $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sigma$ must act as a permutation on the set $\{\sqrt[2]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}\omega, \sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2\}$. Interestingly in this case, all permutations are possible and the Galois group is isomorphic to $S_3$. So to summarize, from the point of view of Galois theory, complex conjugation taking $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$ can be seen at the same level as say another "automorphism" from the Galois group which maps $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$ by sending $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega$ and hence the term "conjugates".
